# Can I tell the JCo version from the files?

Tags: jco

I'm working with an enterprise product that installs and uses the SAP Java Connector.  Is there a way I can tell (e.g. from the installed JAR and DLLs?) what version of JCo it's using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure is you can modify the code or not, thus a general method first.

The class JCo contains a set of methods that returns library wide informations, such a the version :

```
com.sap.conn.jco.JCo.getVersion()
```

you can use if eiter to add a debug info in the application, or to create a small program that link to the used JCo.jar, and display the information.

Otherwise if you simply need to check the marjor version (2 ou 3), JCO version 3 is called "sapjco3.jar" while version 2 is simply "sapjco.jar"

Answer (score 2):

The JCo JAR contains a main method which can be called to display some information like version of JCo JAR itself and of the native library.

You can start it with the following command from the command line, provided both the JAR and the corresponding native lib are in the current directory:

> java -jar sapjco3.jar

This will open a window (on a graphical frontend) or a generate console output (on headless systems) with the information. To force console output you can add `-stdout` to the command (maybe only works on Unix systems).

This is also a good way to check if the JCo JAR fits to the native lib and that you are using the right distribution for your system architecture.

Answer (score 0):

[just right click the jar file and do Run as administrator it will give information about jco version grapically]